# Zabbix 5.2 How to import local .json file to JavaScript preprocessing

Tags: javascript, zabbix

[image]How can I import local (/opt/test.json) .json file to JavaScript preprocessing in Zabbix 5.2? (frontend and zabbix-server on same localhost machine)

It is possible? What ES version is include in Zabbix 5.2? ES5 or ES6?
I need to fetch several keys with values and put to output json. I know how to do last step, but only impor json is an issue right now.

I have tried to use several methods:

require, fetch, httprequest - always somethink wrong

Comment: It's ECMAScript E5/E5.1, with some semantics updated from ES2015+, partial support for ECMAScript 2015 (E6) and ECMAScript 2016 (E7). See https://duktape.org/ for details.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Do you have knowledge how to add some new libraries like require.js or simply import external file to this Zabbix javaScript window?

Comment: No, I don't. If you need something like that, you should probably use an external script and not preprocessing.

Comment: hey, were you trying to get VM IPs? there's a new discovery macro {#VM.IP} in Zabbix 5.2.2 (still unreleased as the time this was wrote, but the RC is already out)